# Remove parameters from url

Tags: javascript, url, parameters

I really don't understand syntax of .replace :D Can someone please fix my code? Now it removes only &chat=1 from URL, but I need it to remove everything from &chat=1 to end of URL.
Sample of URL:

```
http://xxxxxxx.xx/index.php?menu=1&submenu=1&chat=1&od=3&komu=1
```

Result what I need:

```
http://xxxxxxx.xx/index.php?menu=1&submenu=1
```

Result what is my code doing now:

```
http://xxxxxxx.xx/index.php?menu=1&submenu=1&od=3&komu=1
```

Code what I am using now:

```
location.href=location.href.replace(/&?chat=([^&]$|[^&]*)/i, "");
```

Thx for help, sorry for my english :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are using Regular Expressions as part of your replace and based on what you need this expression seems to be simpler and suits your needs:

```
&?chat=.*
```

In Regular Expression

- **`?`** means optional so the `&` is optional may or may not exists in the string.
- **`chat=`** this is expected literally on the string followed by
- **`.*`** this basically means anything else from 0 to as many characters exists in the string.
- **`i`** at the end means case insensitve.

[Online Demo](http://regex101.com/r/lK9wS2/1)

Something like this:

```
"http://xxxxxxx.xx/index.php?menu=1&submenu=1&chat=1&od=3&komu=1".replace(/&?chat=.*/i,"")
//->outputs "http://xxxxxxx.xx/index.php?menu=1&submenu=1"
```